# How to attribute more priority on a specific IntegrationFlow process when there are several IntegrationFlow with SpringIntegration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp, spring-integration-jdbc

I want to attribute more resources (Thread priority) on a specific IntegrationFlow process when there are several IntegrationFlow instances running in a same SpringBoot application using SpringIntegration.

I have two instances of IntegrationFlow linked to two different source types. One is linked to a SFTP source an the other one is linked to a Datasource.
When a SFTP message is consumed after several steps (unzip files containing XML files, check XML files validity against XSD schema, split XML files and persist data corresponding to a part of XML file), a second Workflow, running in parralel, consumes every persisted data from a datasource in order to push them into a Kafka topic. So I want to attribute more resources on the first IntegrationFlow. For every InegrationFlow the max fetch size is setted to one.

Comment: Show some configuration you have so far. Also it is not clear what is “max fetch size”...

Comment: `max-fetch-size` is used to limit the number of files fetched on each poll. The only mechanisms I am aware of is to use a different task executor in each poller with a thread factory that sets the thread priority. Depending on your use case, however, it may be simpler to just use different poll intervals.